# How can I prevent grease buildup on a dishwasher door?

Tags: cleaning, dishwasher

I have noticed significant grease buildup on the bottom of my Whirlpool dishwasher's door. The dishwasher was purchased brand new in the early 2000s.

I have heard that someone has already tried adding vinegar during a wash cycle to no avail. A quick check of the water temperature with a thermometer reveals a hot water temperature of about 105 degrees Fahrenheit from the nearby kitchen faucet.

Furthermore, the problem happens even after I turn on "HIGH TEMP WASH".

What measures can I take to prevent the problem from recurring after cleaning off the buildup?

Comment: rinse your plates off

Comment: If the grease is building up, you might not be using enough soap. And I agreed on pre-rinsing, the more you do in advance, the less strain you put on the dishwasher water filter.

Comment: Some dishwasher require a hot water feed to boost the temps inside the dishwasher. Check your water supply specs.

Comment: I'm very reluctant to try pre-rinsing because the purpose of a dishwasher is to wash dishes. I tried having the dishwasher warm up the water to the required temperature to no avail.

Comment: @ZianChoy all dishwashers have practical limits as to what they can wash. There's a wide range, unfortunately. Some lower end models truly do need you to pre-rinse the plates beforehand.

Comment: Also, have do you regularly clean out the filter? If not, check that. You should clean that out weekly if you can.

Comment: Finally...14 years is a pretty good run for a dishwasher. Might simply be time to get a new one.

Comment: A dishwasher is fundamentally just a sink.  Periodically clean the dishwasher door.

Comment: The water in the dishwater may come from the faucet of 105 degrees but do you know if it is remaining that temperature during the run?  maybe it is getting cold at some point.

Comment: What would be a good way to check the temperature inside a sealed dishwasher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was:

1. Use an Affresh tablet once in a while.
2. Wipe down the bottom of the door periodically.

(In other words, give up and move on with life.)